# Firebase deploy functions - HTTP Error 403

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When trying to deploy my Firebase Functions (after switching computers) I get an error and can't deploy.

> Error: HTTP Error: 403, Service Usage API has not been used in project 563584335869 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/serviceusage.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

I do not have a project with that ID and have switched between projects and it always gives me the exact same project ID.  That link doesn't work for me, but when I put my project ID instead of 563584335869 then it works and the Service Usage API is enable.

Logging out and back in didn't solve the issue, neither did a `firebase init`.

Anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: If you get confusing errors from the Firebas CLI, you should contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I'm getting this error too

Comment: I contacted Firebase support but they aim to get back to me in two working days. I'm hoping to get this resolved sooner.

Comment: Likewise, will update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There was indeed an issue introduced in the deployment of Cloud Functions with Firebase CLI version 7.1.0. The issue has now been fixed on our backend servers, and you should no longer encounter this issue.

If you continue to have problems, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I presume you mean 'has now been fixed'.  Great stuff, it works now.

Comment: Oops... thanks for catching that embarrassing typo. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 8):

I think it may be related to firebase-tools 7.1.0. I back to 7.0.2 and it worked fine.

```
sudo npm uninstall firebase-tools

sudo npm i -g firebase-tools@7.0.2
```

Comment: You right. happened for me right after the update. i did roll back and all is working fine now.

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution. Although this was the correct answer at the time, it's now been fixed and marking this as the answer will mislead people.

Comment: I did basically the same, but just        " sudo npm i -g firebase-tools  "  (after the uninstall).   I guess the present day latest version also doesn't have the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the `project 563584335869` error with Cloud Functions in the Firebase Emulators but not with Cloud Functions in the Firebase Cloud. In the Cloud I was getting a more common error about lack of credentials. I fixed both by adding `Firebase Admin` to the IAM service account for my Cloud Functions.